# Create database using file operation in c language

Tags: c, database, file-handling

I have created a database using files. When inserting a record in the file if the record already exists in the file, it will end up being duplicated. But I want to avoid that. How  can I design a mechanism to avoid duplicating records (i.e., how to check if the record is already in the file and how to stop the same data being entered again by user in the file)?

```
/*  vehicle record program      */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct vehicle
{
    char name[100];
    int lice_no;
    int vehicle_type;
    char cmpny_name[100];
    int menu_year;
}record;

int main(void)
{
    int i , choice;
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char oname[100];
    record det;
    int recsize;
    char c;

    fp1 = fopen("record.dat" , "r+");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        fp1 = fopen("record.dat" , "w+");
        if(fp1 == NULL)
        {
            printf("error in opening file : \n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    recsize = sizeof(det);

    fseek(fp1 , 0 ,SEEK_END);
    printf("Enter owner Name    : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]" , det.name);
    printf("Enter licence number    : ");
    scanf("%d" , &det.lice_no);
    printf("Enter the vehicle type  : ");
    scanf("%d" , &det.vehicle_type);
    scanf("%c" , &c);
    printf("Enter company name  : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]" , det.cmpny_name);
    printf("Enter menufecture year  : ");
    scanf("%d" , &det.menu_year);
    fwrite(&det,recsize,1,fp1);
}
```

Comment: actually i want to check my enter record is already in the file or not...

Comment: Can you create a simpler example? That's way too much code. It would be nice if you made your question more precise. It is not really clear as it is.

Comment: You could also try to create some functions, instead of putting everything in `main()`.

Comment: i don't want to enter the duplicate entry....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before inserting a new record, you must check whether the same record is already in the file. In order to do that, I would start by creating several functions. Something like:

```
void find_record(char *name, record *rec, FILE *f);
void add_record(const record *rec, FILE *f);
void del_record(char *name, FILE *f);
```

I am assuming that `name` alone identifies a given record. Otherwise, you will need to use a composite key (e.g., `name` + `lice_no`).

Once you have all those functions, preventing a duplicate record becomes much easier:

```
void add_record(const record *rec, FILE *f) {
    ...
    record *r;
    find_record(rec->name, r, f);
    if (r == NULL) {
        // record is not already in the file -> insert it
        ...
    }
    else {
        // record is already in the file -> do nothing
        printf("A record with name %s already exists\n", r->name);
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, programming in a modular way really helps a lot, and makes things much easier.

Comment: how to find the record from file...

Comment: You will need to move the file pointer (using `fseek`) to the beginning, and then start traversing all the file, until you find the record you are looking for. For moving from one record to the other you will need to jump `sizeof(record)` bytes using `fseek` again. If additionally you had an [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index), then it would be much easier (and faster) to find a given record. But that will significantly increase the complexity of your program, so you may want to leave that for the future.

Comment: BTW, instead of opening and closing the file for each operation, it might be better to just open it once at the beginning of the program, and close it right before you are exiting the program. That is why I included a parameter `FILE *f` in all the functions in my answer.

Comment: can u integrate in my code....
please.

Comment: anyone can integrate in my code!!!
i want add record but not same or duplicate record.
if user add the record so it's check first that record already exists if not the store in file.

Comment: I already pointed you in the good direction. Now it is time for you to work a bit :) Try to come up with a new solution using functions as I explained in my answer, and ask again if you have troubles.

Comment: brother i don't need a function i want only avoid to store the duplicate data..
and i have trying using fseek but its can't work...

Comment: can you correct the code for me...